# Dealing with an async get method

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I already know that this isn't possible. I'm new to C# and WP development so I just want to learn the best practice, ways how to deal with a situation like this. Here's the code:

```
    public static ObservableCollection<Substance> Substances
    {
        get
        {
            if (_substances == null) await Substance.GetSubstanceDataAsync(); // and nothing gets returned anyway
                else return _substances;
        }
        set
        {
            _substances = value;
        }
    }
```

Should I just call `GetSubstanceDataAsync();` in the App.xaml.cs `OnLaunched()` method and then sort of count on the data being there (throwing an exception if it's null)? Or should I make the `private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)` method on each page async and check for null values every time the page is navigated to and if so, fetch data (this might be the better solution)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, your getter can never be asynchronous. So if you need a resource you can only get through an async method, the getter is clearly not the right place to do it.

What you can do instead is having your property be on an instance of a ViewModel implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). That way, you can notify listeners that your Substance property has changed when your `GetSubstanceDataAsync` task returns. Very conveniently, if you use this property in a XAML binding, the binding will be refreshed automatically.

Comment: Additionally, it may be wise to cache the Task returned by `Substance.GetSubstanceDataAsync` and not start a second task if one already exists...

Answer (score 1):

```
private ObservableCollection<Substance> _substances;
public static ObservableCollection<Substance> Substances
{
    get
    {
        if (_substances == null) {
           GetSubstanceDataAsync();
        }
        return _substances;
    }
    set
    {
        _substances = value;
    }
}

private async void GetSubstanceDataAsync(){
    Substances = await Substance.GetSubstanceDataAsync();
}
```

Now if you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged when you are calling the list first time and it's empty it will launch the async method. When the async method is completed it will update the list and notify the UI that there's update.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different possible approaches, depending on what you actually want to do.

If you want true lazy-initialization, then you should cache the `Task<T>`, i.e., use `Lazy<Task<T>>` (or something like [`AsyncLazy<T>` from my AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncLazy&referringTitle=Documentation)). But if this is for a VM class, then lazy-initialization doesn't really make sense (the View *always* accesses that property).

With a VM, you always load the data, so you can start the loading in the constructor, and update the data (via `INotifyPropertyChanged`/`INotifyCollectionChanged`) when it arrives. The important part to keep in mind is that you want to also handle exceptions cleanly. Note that your UI will have (at least) three different states: Loading, Success, and Error. When the constructor completes, it'll be in the Loading state, and then it will transition to either the Success or Error state.

It's possible to hand-code all this, or you can use a `NotifyTaskCompletion` type described in my [MSDN article on async MVVM data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx) (also [included in my AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NotifyTaskCompletion&referringTitle=Documentation)). `NotifyTaskCompletion` is essentially just a `Task<T>` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so you can respond via data-binding when it completes (successfully or with error).